# How can we connect to snowflake using DB Visualizer using Azure AD

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the following Database URL in DB Visualizer to connect to snowflake using Azure AD authentication

jdbc:snowflake://accountname.snowflakecomputing.com/?authenticator=externalbrowser&warehouse=xxxxx_WH&db=xxx_db&schema=xxxx_schema

I am getting the following error : JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: Exception encountered for HTTP request: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found.

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually indicating that the jvm can't find the necessary certificates.  You can refer to the following link for further troubleshooting:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009LHQMSSA5/how-do-i-resolve-no-trusted-certificate-found-error-when-connecting-to-snowflake-via-jdbc-driver-in-java

See if you can export JAVA_HOME to match the jdk installation where your cacerts is located.  It is usually located under <JAVA_HOME>/lib/security/cacerts.

-pd